# Adding times to existing time in java

Tags: java, date, time, date-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

I am not able to solve below problem please help me.That is i am adding existing time to some some more time (minutes ,seconds or hours).Iam not able to write bellow wt type I wrote i mention that is not given correct answer,

```
String allexam_end_time="18:59:00";//48540000
long oneminute=60000;
try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdfkk = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date reqEndtimekk = sdfkk.parse(allexam_end_time);
    long total=reqEndtimekk.getTime()+oneminute;
    System.out.println("TOtal miliseconds         "+reqEndtimekk.getTime()+oneminute);
    System.out.println("total---------"+total);
    int s = (int)(total / 1000) % 60;
    int m = (int)(total / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    int h=  (int) (total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
    System.out.println(h+":"+m+":"+s);
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

### Output

```
    output is TOtal miliseconds4854000060000
    total---------48600000
    13:30:0
```

But I need answer that if  added one minute means outputshould 19:00:00
        How can solve?

Comment: `}catch(Exception e){

    }`  Never do that in broken code.  Change it to `}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace(); 
    }`

Comment: @user1906191 please tell me what actually you want ? you want to find difference between two times in minutes ,seconds and hours???

Answer (score 1):

You can use GregorianCalendar, here is a code example:

```
    String allexam_end_time = "18:59:00";// 48540000
    SimpleDateFormat sdfkk = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date reqEndtimekk = sdfkk.parse(allexam_end_time);
    Calendar instance = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    instance.setTime(reqEndtimekk);
    //add one minute        
    instance.add(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 1);

    System.out.println(sdfkk.format(instance.getTime()));
```

The output

```
07:00:00
```

Comment: I want in 19:00:00 this format

Comment: just change the 'hh' of the SimpleDateFormat to 'HH' and it will the show 19 instead 7 :)

Comment: Hi please tell me how can i add milliseconds, I do not want to pass as 60,i want to pass milliseconds how can i add 18:59:00+miliseconds want ans in 19:00:00 format please

Comment: change the GregorianCalendar.MINUTE to GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND... so to one minute it should be: instance.add(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND, 60000);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help!

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String examEndTime = "18:59:00";

        System.out.println(modifyTime(examEndTime, 60));
    }

    private static String modifyTime(String origTime, int modSecs) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        timeFormat.setLenient(false);
        Date time = timeFormat.parse(origTime);
        time.setSeconds(modSecs);
        return timeFormat.format(time);
    }

}
```

The output will be
`19:00:00`

Comment: Hi please tell me how can i add milliseconds, I do not want to pass as 60,i want to pass milliseconds how can i add 18:59:00+miliseconds want ans in 19:00:00 format please

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that your code, as it is, may be doing some time zone conversions.
For example, I calculate 18:59:00 to be (18*60*60 + 59*60)*1000 = **68340000** ms. But if I put the same thing into Java and call getTime(), I get **39540000** ms, and you get **48540000**.

Some of these other replies are better ways of solving your issue (one major thing is calling sdfkk.format(reqEndtimekk) at the end rather than getting h/m/s again), but your but seems to be around time zones.